# How to import existing GCP infrastructure into the Terraform module?

Tags: import, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to import the existing vm instance into Terraform

`terraform import google_compute_instance.vm_instance "7693284469019008963"`

but I keep getting the error "Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module."

I've already created the config in main.tf, but the errors still persist. Can someone help me, please ? TIA !

[my directory] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4f5a.png)

[main.tf] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJcSD.png)

[error] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpViH.png)

Comment: Tip: test only on throw-away instances in a test project. Terrafrom can destroy resources.

Answer (score 0):

If that top-level `main.tf` file is also supposed to be part of the module, you are missing the module definition and the module prefix for the import:

```
module "main" {
  source = "./modules"
}
```

And

```
terraform import module.main.google_compute_instance.vm_instance "7693284469019008963"
```

If it's not supposed to be part of a module, the `main.tf` file needs to be outside the `modules` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hashicorp released a [new import feature](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/state/state-import) in version 1.5 that can be helpful in your usecase.

Terraform will automatically generate the source code of the resource you need to import.

You should create a "import.tf":

```
import {
  to = google_compute_instance.vm_instance
  id = "projects/[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]/zones/[ZONE]/instances/[INSTANCE_NAME]"
}
```

Then, run the command `terraform plan -generate-config-out=generated.tf` and a new file will be generated with the resource you want to import. Then you just need to `terraform apply` and everything should be set.

Hope it helps :)